# Detecting insert/update/delete in CakePHP's AppController's afterFilter method

Tags: database, cakephp, controller, detection

I have some code I've added to the `afterFilter()` method of my `AppController` (`/app/app_controller.php`) in a CakePHP app I'm developing.  This code rebuilds a large, static file and I only want to incur the overhead of that rebuild when a record has been inserted, updated, or deleted.  Apart from setting some sort of flag in every controller's actions that perform an update, is there a way to detect whether the database has been modified during a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model (app_model if you want it for every model) you may use [afterSave function](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1053/afterSave) you may use it just when you do a save/saveAll that normally is what you use to create/uodate in cake.

Also you have the [afterDelete method](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1055/afterDelete) to do it when you delete something.

hope this helps you :)